# What is the meaning of using a comma expression in a method call, such as `var proc = (0, _postcss2.default)();`

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Looking at cssnano source code, I came across this line

`var proc = (0, _postcss2.default)();`

From what I've tested, it seems to do the same thing as

`var proc = _postcss2.default();`

Why did cssnano assign `proc` using the first syntax?

Comment: Both lines do do the same thing. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator As for why cssnano did it the first way, I couldn't say.

Comment: @nnnnnn Not quite, I'll write an answer.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - OK, well it would change the value of `this` within the function - is that what you mean? Guess I'll wait and see your answer...

Comment: @nnnnnn Yep, that's the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a subtle difference, in that the `this` value is different in `default` based on the two different calls. Consider the following code:

```js
var _postcss2 = {
    default: function() {
        return this;
    }
};

var proc = (0, _postcss2.default)();
console.log(proc); // proc === window (or undefined in strict mode)

var proc = _postcss2.default();
console.log(proc); // proc === _postcss2
```

`_postcss2.default()` calls `default` as a method of the `_postcss2` object and sets `this` accordingly, but `(0, _postcss2.default)();` does not, and `this` would be `window` in non-strict-mode, and `undefined` in strict-mode.

The way [the comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) works, is that all the expressions are executed, but only the final expression is returned, so `0,` is a short meaningless expression to use the comma operator to get the function reference itself, without setting it to a variable first.

If that makes a difference in this particular case, I cannot say without looking at the code itself.

The [corresponding line from the source code](https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano/blob/8ee81eae5b7e95b214f95f3663ef9a0124107a24/src/index.js#L110) for this code is, `let proc = postcss();`, with `postcss` being an ES6 import. This particular code is being generated by an ES6 transpiler, probably Babel.

Comment: Good answer, although it raises the question of why the `default` method would use `this` if it's not intended to be called that way.

Comment: You might want to add something about what the comma operator does, and why that changes things when the function call is made.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, the only thing I can think of is a hackish way of accessing the global `this` in both browsers and Node without `typeof`. Not something I would do though, I put everything in strict mode.

Comment: @nnnnnn Good call, I've added a short overview.

Comment: @Barmar Turns out it's something what I presume is Babel is generating for ES6 imports. Not sure exactly why though.